# Integration of R and SAP HANA using RJDBC

Tags: r, jdbc, hana, rjdbc

I am trying to connect R-Studio Server with Sap Hana to fetch a view and perform analyses. I am basically using a citrix environment so I don't have access to the C: drive. Rather I have the hdbclient folder in sap stored in z: drive. The code I am using is as follows:

```
install.packages("RJDBC")
library("RJDBC")

jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver",  
              classPath="Z/SAP/hdbclient/ngdbc.jar")
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver,
              "jdbc:sap://ukhana.mo.sap.corp:30015/?autocommit=false"
              ,"username"
              ,"password")
```

However, upon executing the jdbcDriver <- command, I am getting an error "Error in jfindClass(as.character(driverclass)[1]): class not found." Please help me as I am not understanding how to proceed ahead.

Comment: Your classpath looks off to me.  Are you running Windows or Unix?

Comment: Windows, it's a citrix VM

Comment: I access it using an online link, but on a windows  virtual machine.

Comment: Try `classPath="Z:/SAP/hdbclient/ngdbc.jar"` ... you were using what looks like a Linux-style file path, though I doubt that would have worked on Linux either.

Comment: I was entering this path only, typing mistake in the question, I don't get the error

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, do you have some other alternative of fetching a view from sap hana in R.

Comment: @AshminKaul Please clarify, is the problem solved? If not **edit** your question with the corrected code. As it stands it looks as if this question is a "typo" problem (invalid path).